# If in a data.frame

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to choose a value between two columns in the same row following values in other columns.

My function would be like: if values inside shapiro1, shapiro2 and F_test are less than 0.05 choose value in t_test else choose wilcox's value. Does it seem possible to you to make a function like this and apply on a larger columns?

```
structure(list(modalities = structure(1:3, .Label = c("BS1", 
"HW1", "PG"), class = "factor"), shapiro1 = c(0.0130672654432492, 
0.305460485386201, 0.148320635833262), shapiro2 = c(0.920315823302857, 
0.1354174735521, 0.148320635833262), F_test = c(0.20353475323665, 
0.00172897172228584, 1), t_test = c(2.88264982135322e-06, 5.75374264225996e-05, 
NaN), wilcox = c(0.00909069801592506, 0.00902991076269246, NaN
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: If with "values inside" you mean the sum of these three variables, then see @Ronak's answer. Otherwise you can do `ifelse(df1$shapiro1 & df1$shapiro2 & df1$F_test < 0, df1$t_test, df1$wilcox)`

Comment: `if values inside shapiro1, shapiro2 and F_test are less than 0.05`... Do you mean **all** values or **any** values ? I have considered **any**.

Comment: I was not looking for the sum, sorry be confusing. Thank all of you, Both of your scripts work. I was looking for patL's script, do you know how to keep modalities code? I was considering not the sum of values, but each values have to be less than <0.05 in a row. You may have an idea about another subject I created (a previous script where i struggled to pass out) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450641/apply-function-with-two-arguments-after-subsetting-by-factors And If this one works i could implement into another script instead of F_test which is less powerfull than Bartlett.test

Comment: Btw you may know how can i create a condition has: if value is less than 0.0001 replace it by ****, and if it less than 0.001 replace it by ***, 0.01 **, 0.05 *

Comment: @Simon If you want each value to be less than 0.05 you can try `ifelse(rowSums(df[cols] < 0.05) == length(cols), df$t_test, df$wilcox)` taking `cols` from my below answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select columns, apply `rowSums` and check if any value in that row is less than 0.05 and select `t_test` or `wilcox` values accordingly.

```
cols <- c("shapiro1", "shapiro2", "F_test")
ifelse(rowSums(df[cols] < 0.05) > 0, df$t_test, df$wilcox)
#[1] 2.882650e-06 5.753743e-05          NaN
```